# CircleCI: How to Handle Java OOM Errors

Tags: android, circleci, circleci-2.0

Get OOM error when I run test on CircleCI, like this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 137

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Part of the configuration of my config.yml file:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build-and-test:   
    working_directory: ~/carepilot-android/
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-25-alpha

    environment:

      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m             
      CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
      CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS: /tmp/circleci-test-results

    steps:
      - checkout
    ...
```

I tried changing the "environment" configuration:

```
environment:
  TERM: dumb
  _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"     
  GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true'
```

or:

```
environment:
  JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m
```

I still get the OOM error.

Please help or try to give some ideas how to fix this.

Comment: Is it possible that your test runner spawns a new VM to run the tests in? Surefire does that.

Comment: `environment:        
      
      _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Xms1000m -Xmx1436m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1436m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -XX:ConcGCThreads=1 -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=2"
      GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx1500m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Dorg.gradle.workers.max=1 -Dorg.gradle.parallel=false -DdisablePreDex'   `

Comment: I changed to the above settings, it worked.